# Is it safe to bypass a battery?

Tags: wiring, batteries

I have an old camera which Im tinkering with and when I opened it up I found that the battery (liPo) is puffy. As I dont have a spare I can't replace it and Im beginning to doubt myself that its safe to just put a wire there instead. I will be plugging it in to a 5v usb.

TL;DR: Can I put a wire in place of a battery?

Edit: It has a built in 5v usb port, which is what I intend on using to power the device. I would like to know a safe way of removing the battery, so that it will only be powered when plugged in.

Comment: Are you trying to find a way to simply use the device with the faulty battery removed? Maybe let's ask that instead? I'm thinking that would be inherently safer. Short circuit (with wire) is almost never good.

Comment: Yes I would like to find a safe way to operate it, with a power supply (usb) instead of a possibly bad battery. The camera works when plugged in but I would be at ease with the battery gone. Should also mention it has a built in usb port.

Comment: OK, let's add that information to (edit) your question. Does the camera have an existing 5V input usb, or are you planning to attach wires from USB port somewhere into the camera?

Comment: There is a charge controller IC. Plus processor also collects the status of the battery. There should be a high probability of happening something wrong. You should consult the customer care of your device.

Comment: Some cameras will work on just the usb port with no batteries inside. Otherwise you could try to make a battery eliminator like https://www.instructables.com/id/cheap-and-easy-PSU-for-Canon-EOS/ or https://www.instructables.com/id/USB-Powered-Camera-PowerShot-Battery-Hack/

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried just running the device off your USB power without a battery? possibly with an electrolytic cap in place of the battery?

If this doesn't work when i wanted to have a wired wii mote, i just soldered a 5v to 3v SOT-223 LDO to the battery prongs (and some ceramic caps) and wired it to a USB cable. This is essentially what @Passerby is talking about with his Battery Eliminator.

Also like @Elliot Alderson said, don't short your battery terminals with a wire. If the device doesn't work because it cuts off the USB power if there is no battery, then you can simulate a load with a 1k through hole resistor to make it look like a battery is being charged.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried cutting the battery out altogether and leaving the wires loose and it seemed to work. The ic did seem to get quite warm after this but I dont know how hot it got before so I think its ok. Would adding a resistor be worth it if its working?

Comment: if it works it works, but i dont know which IC you're referring to

Comment: Just the main chip on the pcb, but nvm. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not safe. If the camera tries to charge the "battery" you may get a very high current through the wire, causing it to get hot and possibly cause a fire.

Comment: Is there a way to safely measure this current, an if so do you know how I could limit it? Thanks

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to put a wire in place of the battery cell, it is an absurd idea, useless, and quite dangerous too.

Comment: ...Or, if it doesn't get hot, that's because the power supply limited the current in some way, and as a result, it almost certainly will not maintain sufficent voltage to operate the camera.

Comment: Absolutely no reason except every reason https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_eliminator

Comment: How will the camera try to charge the battery?

Comment: @Passerby Assuming that you are asking me that question...note that I said "**if** the camera tries to charge". It was not clear from the OP's question whether the battery is charged in the camera or outside the camera and I wanted to err on the side of caution.

Comment: @Passerby, Most digital cameras will charge the battery if a battery is installed, and the camera is supplied with external power. How? Well, the camera and/or the battery pack itself contain battery charging circuitry. Smart battery chargers can be _very_ small these days.

Answer (score 1):

A wire in the place of a battery cell is dangerous as it would short out the charging circuit inside of the camera. It would be better to simulate the battery and provide ~3.6V (for each cell, a once cell will be 3.4 a two cell will be 7.2V)  to the camera through the battery terminals (remember to get the polarity right, **and make sure if you do simulate a battery, that the usb charger or any other charger is never connected**). I have a DSLR that has an adapter that does a similar thing.